# IBM Watson Assistant: How do I integrate a Chatbot into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How do I implement a IBM Watson Chatbot from IBM Cloud into Unity?

Main aim is to implement a chatbot in Unity with an avatar and I want to implement IBM Watson Chatbot in Unity.

How do I get started?

Answer (score 0):

IBM provides a [Unity SDK for the Watson services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk). It has [code samples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/master/Examples), including for the IBM Watson Assistant. There is even a [starter for Watson Assistant](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/master/Scripts/Services/Assistant/V2).